# How can I use BibTeX to cite software?

Tags: bibtex, citing

I want to cite software in the following format using BibTeX:

`[author], [software name], [version number], [year], available at [URL]`

How can I do this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/5001) The title of your posting mentions BibTeX, yet you've tagged both "bibtex" and "biblatex", which are two different systems. Please advise which system you intend to use. If it's BibTeX, please also indicate which bibliography style you employ.

Comment: i use bibtex and bibliography style is IEEEtran.sty

Comment: Bibliography style files end in `.bst`, not `.sty`.  What's the argument of the `\bibliographystyle` instruction in your document?

Comment: @Mico I would rather say that [BibTeX and the `biblatex` package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/299286/64454) are intrinsically different. The former is a program that processes a `.bib` file, when the latter is a LaTeX package. One can thus use both together (even if biber is often recommended over BibTeX - ymmv though). Whatever it be, the bibliographic style is however an important information to provide.

Comment: @ebo - I used the term "system" in a deliberately not very precise way. (I *am* aware that BibTeX is an executable program and that `biblatex` is a LaTeX package...) The purpose of my comment was purely to elicit more usable information from the OP. I'm afraid I wasn't particularly successful, though. :-(

Comment: @Mico I of course supposed it was the case. It's just that the whole biblatex, bibtex, biber, natbib thing used to confuse me so much that since I got the difference I tend to engage in proselytizing that particular question (sometimes too much?!) `(-;`

Answer (score 34):

<sup>This answer is an adapted copy of [the original one](https://superuser.com/a/900254/698991) provided by [Pascal](https://superuser.com/users/118158/pascal) on SuperUser. It is copied here as a community wiki for archival purpose.</sup>

---

If you use the *package* `biblatex`, you can thus use the `@software` entry-
 type in your database:

```
@software{hadoop,
  author = {{Apache Software Foundation}},
  title = {Hadoop},
  url = {https://hadoop.apache.org},
  version = {0.20.2},
  date = {2010-02-19},
}
```

Produces

> Apache Software Foundation. Hadoop. Version 0.20.2. Feb. 19, 2010.
>   URL: https://hadoop.apache.org

Comment: For some reason I'm getting `Package biblatex Warning: No driver for entry type 'software'. Using fallback driver on input line 191.`? It seems to be outputting the correct output but still giving a warning

Comment: @JMY1000 Thanks for your comment. I suggest you ask a separate question if you want help on you issue (potentially back-referencing to this question), so that it can benefit others too.

Comment: Unfortunately, this entry type seems to be ignored when used for separated sections of the bibliography (using the `keywords` trick). (with biblatex 2017/11/21 v3.9)

Comment: What I found particularly useful about this was the fact that I can force `Apache Software Foundation` to not be abbreviated as `A. S. Foundation` by using curly braces around the foundation name: `author = {{Apache Software Foundation}}`

Answer (score 18):

How about

```
@misc{blabla,
  author = {author name},
  title = {software name (version ...)},
  year  = {year},
  url   = {url},
}
```

I think that would be completely valid. You could also use the `note` field to add information.