# Citing software with biblatex

Tags: bibtex, apa-style, apa6

I want to cite software in APA style, this is what APA requires (Example for R):

R Core Team. (2019). R: A Language and Environment for Statistical Computing. Version 3.6.1 [Computer Software]. Vienna, Austria. Retrieved from https://www.R-project.org/ (EPEL Repo)

The following prints [Computer Software Manual] - is there are way to have "Manual" removed?

```
@Manual{RCT2019,
  author       = {{R Core Team}},
  title        = {{R: A Language and Environment for Statistical Computing. Version 3.6.1}},
  year         = {2019},
  howpublished = {Vienna, Austria},
  date         = {2019},
  organization = {R Foundation for Statistical Computing},
  location     = {Vienna, Austria},
  url          = {https://www.R-project.org/ (EPEL Repo)},
}
```

Ref: https://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2015/01/how-to-cite-software-in-apa-style.html

```
\documentclass[doc,natbib,floatsintext,12pt,noextraspace]{apa6}
```

```
\section*{REFERENCES}
\label{sec:REFERENCES}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{REFERENCES}
\end{center}
\renewcommand{\bibsection}{}    % hides/removes References from the bibliography 
\urlstyle{same}                 % needed to surpress the typewrite style of ULR
\raggedright % without it, spaces between authors and titles too wide.
\bibliography{../Diss-Bibliography.bib}
```

Comment: Can you please post the code of a small, compilable dokument that shows the problem as well as your document setup?

Comment: Ok, added above, what I think matters :-|

Comment: A [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) would be nice

Comment: From the code shown so far it is pretty clear that you are not using `biblatex`, but it isn't quite clear to me which style you are using. Could you turn the code snippets shown so far into a fully compilable example document (an MWE https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864 or MWEB https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864), please?

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone is facing the same problem in 2021: I don't know which APA version the original question was referring to, but according to APA 7, the software's name should be in italics and followed by the software version in parentheses (See [https://libraryguides.vu.edu.au/apa-referencing/7DatasetsSoftwareTests#s-lg-box-wrapper-24941466] for reference). So the entry should look like this:

R Core Team. (2019). *R: A Language and Environment for Statistical Computing*  (Version 3.6.1) [Computer Software]. Vienna, Austria. https://www.R-project.org %20(EPEL%20Repo)

I'm using biblatex with biber backend, and the following bibtex entry produced the desired output:

```
@software{RCT2019,
  author       = {{R Core Team}},
  year         = {2019},
  title        = {R: A Language and Environment for Statistical Computing},
  url          = {https://www.R-project.org/ (EPEL Repo)},
  version      = {3.6.1},
  note         = {Computer Software},
  howpublished = {Vienna, Austria},
  date         = {2019},
  organization = {R Foundation for Statistical Computing},
  location     = {Vienna, Austria}
}
```

Example for software developed by a single person (leaving out location):

```
@software{Birkholz.2020,
  author = {Birkholz, P.},
  year = {2020},
  title = {VocalTractLab},
  url = {https://www.vocaltractlab.de/index.php?},
  version = {2.3},
  note = {Computer Software}
}
```

Output:

Birkholz, P. (2020). *VocalTractLab* (Version 2.3) [Computer Software]. https://www.vocaltractlab.de/index.php?

Answer (score 1):

Here are four solutions.

**Add a type field to the bib-entry of the manual**

Add `type = {Computer Software}` to the bib-entry of the manual such that it reads

```
@Manual{RCT2019,
  author       = {{R Core Team}},
  title        = {{R: A Language and Environment for Statistical Computing. Version 3.6.1}},
  year         = {2019},
  howpublished = {Vienna, Austria},
  date         = {2019},
  organization = {R Foundation for Statistical Computing},
  location     = {Vienna, Austria},
  url          = {https://www.R-project.org/ (EPEL Repo)},
  type         = {Computer Software}
}
```

**Redefine the command \bibcomputersoftwaremanual**

If you don't want to edit all bib entries as required for the solution above, add the line

```
\let\bibcomputersoftwaremanual\bibcomputersoftware
```

before the `\bibliography` command.

**Patch the bibliography style apacite.bst**

Copy the bibtex style `apacite.bst` (located e.g. in `/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/apacite/`) to the directory where you run `bibtex`. It contains the function definition

```
FUNCTION {manual}
{ %
  % If type is empty, assume that it is a computer software manual.
  %
  type empty$
    { "\bibcomputersoftwaremanual"  'type.2 := }
    'skip$
  if$
  misc
}
```

Replace the string `\bibcomputersoftwaremanual` by `\bibcomputersoftware`.

**Change bib entry type @Manual to @Misc**

With type `@Misc`, no extra strings like `Computer software manual` will be added by the bibliography style, you have to add them manually to the bib entry to the appropriate field.

Comment: Thanks, but the title is in italics with your solution, at least on my end.
 What is loading apacite.bst? Is that in the picture because I am using natbib in the documentclass? Or would it be anyways present in any Latex document?

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't lead anywhere. Since you did not provide a small compilable sample document that illustrates your problem, we work with different settings. The sample document that I composed from the few clues in your posting *does not* have italic titles.

Comment: @togedo So, compose a small compilable document that shows what is wrong, and then ask a new question. Do not try to guess 'what matters' - you can't.

Comment: Ok, I'd like to provide a small doc, but my *.bib file is external,not sure how I can include bib entries directly in the tex file without adding an extra package do to this.

Comment: @togedo - Read this: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4408/29873 and prepare your code accordingly

Comment: @DG, tried to add the packages and got a whole list of errors and warnings. I already achieved what I wanted. Will not spend more time on this issue. I appreciate very much your efforts to help.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, in case anyone needs this:

```
@Software{RCT2019,
  author       = {{R Core Team}},
  date         = {2010-02-19},
  howpublished = {{R: A Language and Environment for Statistical Computing. Version 3.6.1 [Computer Software]. Vienna, Austria}},
  note         = {EPEL Repo},
  url          = {https://www.R-project.org/ },
}
```

Comment: This does not seem to be a solution to the problem as stated in your posting. `bibtex` complains that `@Software` is an unknown entry type. Maybe you use a bibtex style other than the default `apacite.bst` that defines it, but this is not clear from your posting.

Comment: yes, bitex complains, but the output is correct. I found this solution here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254610/how-can-i-use-bibtex-to-cite-a-software

Comment: What happens is that bibtex treats the unknown entry type `@Software` as `@Misc`. So better use this one from the outset.

Comment: hm, ok, works for me too, Thank you!!